# How can I extract data from a string in any order using PowerShell and Regex?

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to solve this problem using PowerShell and Regex. I have a string variable like the following:

```
$input = @"
Server Time: 4/13/2016 12:29 PM
Username: RBullwinkle
Lorem ipsum dolor Important Data: rosebud sit amet
"@;
```

I would like to extract data such that I receive the following result:

```
$serverTime = "4/13/2016 12:29 PM"
$userName = "RBullwinkle"
$important = "rosebud"
```

This would be a straightforward regex except for the following complications:

1. I would like the extraction to be robust to any changes in the order of the data.
2. I would like to process the input string in a single pass.

Comment: For data that is structured nicely like this use `ConvertFrom-StringData`. You can do that with very little regex. Just need to change the : to = and it should work. I have a few posts about this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

credit goes to @sweaver2112 for the regex work, but i thought i'd add this to show one way to convert this information into a powershell object

```
$input1 = @'
Server Time: 4/13/2016 12:29 PM
Username: RBullwinkle
Lorem ipsum dolor Important Data: rosebud sit amet
'@

$input2 = @'
Lorem ipsum dolor Important Data: daffodils are lovely
Server Time: 4/13/2016 12:29 PM
Username: RBullwinkle
'@

$regex = 'Server\sTime:\s?(?<servertime>.*)|Username:\s?(?<username>.*)|Important\sData:\s?(?<importantdata>\w+)'
$matches1 = [regex]::matches($input1, $regex)
$matches2 = [regex]::matches($input2, $regex)

$hash1 = @{}
$matches1 | % {
    if ($_.Success) {
        $value = $_.value -split ': '
            $hash1.Add($value[0].trim(), $value[1].trim())
    }
}

$hash2 = @{}
$matches2 | % {
    if ($_.Success) {
        $value = $_.value -split ': '
            $hash2.Add($value[0].trim(), $value[1].trim())
    }
}

[pscustomobject]$hash1, [pscustomobject]$hash2
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use .NET framework regular expressions that will let you do a global (do not return on first match) match, combined with alternation to match what you want. [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJ1bZ4/1) is easily shown (check your match info), the powershell commands might be something like this (admittedly, I'm not a powershell guy):

```
$myinput = @"
Server Time: 4/13/2016 12:29 PM
Username: RBullwinkle
Lorem ipsum dolor Important Data: rosebud sit amet
"@
$myotherinput = @"
Lorem ipsum dolor Important Data: daffodils are lovely
Server Time: 4/13/2016 12:29 PM
Username: RBullwinkle
"@

$pattern = "Server\sTime:\s?(?<servertime>.*)|Username:\s?(?<username>.*)|Important\sData:\s?(?<importantdata>\w+)"
$mymatches = [regex]::matches($myinput, $pattern)
$myothermatches = [regex]::matches($myotherinput, $pattern)

$mymatches | ForEach-Object { if ( $_.Success) { echo $_.value}}

#Server Time: 4/13/2016 12:29 PM
#Username: RBullwinkle
#Important Data: rosebud

$myothermatches | ForEach-Object { if ( $_.Success) { echo $_.value}}

#Important Data: daffodils
#Server Time: 4/13/2016 12:29 PM
#Username: RBullwinkle
```