# Capturing multiple points of data from a text file using Regex in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

So I got this regex expression to work in Regex101 and it captures exactly what I want to capture. https://regex101.com/r/aJ1bZ4/3

But when I try the same thing in powershell all I get is the first set of matches. I've tried using the (?s:), the (?m:) but none of these modifiers seem to do the job. Here is my powershell script.

```
$reportTitleList = type ReportExecution.log | Out-String |
where {$_ -match "(?<date>\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}).*ID=(?<reportID>.*):.*Started.*Title=(?<reportName>.*)\[.*\n.*Begin ....... (?<reportHash>.*)"} |
foreach {
    new-object PSObject -prop @{
        Date=$matches['date']
        ReportID=$matches['reportID']
        ReportName=$matches['reportName']
        ReportHash=$matches['reportHash']
    }
}

$reportTitleList > reportTitleList.txt
```

What am I doing wrong? Why am I not getting all the matches as the regex101 example?

Comment: The powershell pipeline is getting individual lines of the file and passing them into `where`, but your regex is a multiline regex containing `\n`. The regex will never see a newline character, or the "started", "begin", "end" lines at once, so it won't match properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-match` only find the first match. To use a global search you need to use `[regex]::Matches()` or `Select-String` with the `-AllMatches` switch. Ex:

```
#In PoweShell 3.0+ you can replace `Get-Content | Out-String` with `Get-Content -Raw`
$reportlist = Get-Content -Path ReportExecution.log | Out-String |
Select-String -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches |
Select-Object @{n="Date";e={$_.Groups["date"]}},
              @{n="ReportID";e={$_.Groups["reportID"]}},
              @{n="ReportName";e={$_.Groups["reportName"]}},
              @{n="ReportHash";e={$_.Groups["reportHash"]}}

#Show output
$reportlist
```

Output:

```
Date       ReportID ReportName                                                             ReportHash                       
----       -------- ----------                                                             ----------                       
2015/03/23 578      Calendar Day Activity/Calendar Day Activity                            38C19F4E790446709B8C7A32FF97BC...
2015/03/23 861      Program Format Report/Program Format Report                            3C9CB2150AF14B15A1B361729C007B...
2015/03/23 1077     Multi-Station Program Availability/Multi-Station Program Availability  52526430EE4E401BA4376B38A2D88B...
2015/03/23 1299     Program Audit Trail/Program Audit Trail                                FDD1B7D9F34E46549A377A17B9A7A1...
2015/03/23 1541     Program Availability/Program Availability                              843B44F4475C4950A7784C8961B642...
2015/03/23 1756     Program Description Export/Program Description Export                  E5800A76C68E4D5281B8D680DB2E93...
```

Comment: so the $pattern wold just be the same regex101 pattern or do I need to modify it?

Comment: Pattern should be the same regex

Comment: Data field? The hash you mean?  It's truncated because of the console/screen buffer width, but you can access it by using the property. Ex: `$reportlist[0].ReportHash`  (first item only). To export this to a file you should use `Export-CSV` or create a string etc. You should not redirect the screen output itself as it will truncate data.

Comment: So I am using the same method on another set of data and again regex101 matches while powershell doesnt https://regex101.com/r/xG8oX2/1

   
`$reportLayoutIDList = Get-Content -Path bigOptions.txt | Out-String |
Select-String -Pattern $pattern2 -AllMatches |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches |
Select-Object @{n="ReportHash";e={$_.Groups["reportHash"]}},
              @{n="LayoutID";e={$_.Groups["reportLayoutID"]}};$reportLayoutIDList`


Is there a modifier I need to use in the regex for powershell?

Comment: The problem is your linebreaks. In windows, linebreaks are CRLF (`\r\n`) while in UNIX etc. they're just LF `\n`. So either you need to modify the input to only use `LF` or you need to replace `\n` with `\r\n` in your regex to make it Windows-compatible. This should have been a different SO-question. :-)

Comment: Thank you. Did that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052703/how-to-modify-this-regex-to-work-in-powershell

Comment: Oh. Haha.  It was actually just a tip for the future.

Answer (score 1):

`-match` returns as soon as it finds a match (they should have a `-matches` operator right?). If you want multiple matches, use:

`$mymatches = [regex]::matches($input,$pattern)`

output will be different than `-match`, however, and you'll have to massage it a bit, something like: (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608011/how-can-i-extract-data-from-a-string-in-any-order-using-powershell-and-regex/36612487#36612487) for another example of conversion)

`$mymatches | ForEach-Object { if ( $_.Success) { echo $_.value}}`