# How to modify this regex to work in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

So I have this regex https://regex101.com/r/xG8oX2/2 which gives me the matches I want.

But when I run this powershell script, it give me no matches. What should I modify in this regex to be able to get the same matches in powershell?

```
$pattern2 = '\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}.*]\s(?<reportHash>.*):.*Start.*\r*\n*.*\n.*ReportLayoutID=(\d{1,7})';
$reportLayoutIDList = Get-Content -Path bigOptions.txt | Out-String |
Select-String -Pattern $pattern2 -AllMatches |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches |
Select-Object @{n="ReportHash";e={$_.Groups["reportHash"]}},
              @{n="LayoutID";e={$_.Groups["reportLayoutID"]}};$reportLayoutIDList | 
Export-csv reportLayoutIDList.csv;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your linebreaks. In windows, linebreaks are CRLF (`\r\n`) while in UNIX etc. they're just LF `\n`.

So either you need to modify the input to only use LF or you need to replace `\n` with `\r\n` in your regex.

As @briantist mentioned, using `\r?\n` will match either way.

Comment: I typically like to use `\r?\n` for linebreaks to catch either case.

Comment: Smart :-). Updated

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to both Frode F and briantist.

This is the regex pattern that worked in Powershell:

`$pattern2 = '\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}.*]\s(?<reportHash>.*):.*Start.*[\r?\n]*.*[\r?\n].*ReportLayoutID=(?<reportLayoutID>\d+)';`

Comment: I think the intent was `(?:\r?\n)*`. This `[..]` is a character class and not the same thing. If you're worried about the `\r` as a linebreak, the universal expression is `(?:\r?\n|\r)`